# Uncaught Type error while using C on Atom IDE

Tags: c, atom-editor

So I have only used atom for Python until now but I tried running C code on it and its showing at RHS of the screen with a red message
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`
I have my editor set at C language so there is no problem with that.Is it the problem with the script package?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a C question to me...

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem in Atom editor for "C language" as- "uncaught type error"
then try these things-

1. Save the atom file with .c extension else it won't work for c program.
2. Check whether you have installed "gpp-compiler".

Though if the program doesn't work then, check whether your program is correct.